# Including *any* query string in my site URL causes a 404

Tags: php, string, http, url

First I apologize if this has already been asked; I used the SO search & advanced search and even an hours' worth of GoogleFu, all to no avail.

The issue I'm having is that any time I try and use a query in my URL it causes a 404.

127.0.0.1/login.php throws an error saying the required query (&asdfasdf=?) doesn't exist, but otherwise works fine... http://puu.sh/2SIyc.png

127.0.0.1/login.php&asdfasdf=5 causes 404... http://puu.sh/2SIxF.png

What I've tried:
Through my extensive searching, a lot of results turned up that certain query names "aren't allowed" if they're already used by the CMS in question. This isn't using a CMS, and even if there's something funky in the PHP back-end which claims some query names, I doubt they're called "asdfasdf" like mine.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
<?php include('header.php') ?>

<!-- Primary Content -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12" style="border: 1px solid #000;">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <?php 
        $error = $_GET["asdfasdf"]; 
        if(is_null($error)){
          echo "<h1> THE &asdfasdf=X RESOLVED TO NULL </h1>";
        } else {
          echo "<h1> Your passwords did not match </h1>";
        }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="login-container">

      <!-- Left-hand-side; login form-->
      <div class="span6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group" id="sign-in">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me </input>
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Right-hand-side; register form-->
      <div class="span6" id="register-container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="register-container" method="post" action="register_validate.php">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <span class="help-block indented-help-block">This will be your username.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPasswordConfirmation">Confirm password</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="password" id="passwordConfirmation" name="passwordConfirmation" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group" id="register">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox">Log in immediately</input>
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: any mod_rewrite occuring? probably a bad rewrite.

Comment: Try using a `?` instead of `&` for the first parameter. ie `127.0.0.1/login.php?asdfasdf=5` instead of `127.0.0.1/login.php&asdfasdf=5`

Comment: You'd usually start a querystring with a question mark, otherwise it's part of the URL, and that will certainly give you a 404. It's actually such an uncommon mistake that I'll vote to close this, as you should have figured this out for yourself, and it will be of no help to others.

Comment: @brbcoding This was my problem! Simply replacing the & with ? for the first query fixed it. Thank you!!!

Comment: @user2275203, good, I added it as an answer below.

Comment: This could of been figured out by looking at ANY query string ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `?` instead of `&` for the first parameter. 
`127.0.0.1/login.php?asdfasdf=5` 
instead of 
`127.0.0.1/login.php&asdfasdf=5`

Answer (score 1):

Query string should start at the following format.

SOME-SITE/SOME-PAGE.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&...

Of course no parameters required..
the main thing should be the question mark between the page and the query string.
and ampersand between the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `&` with a `?`. You need to tell PHP that you've got a query string. A question mark is the way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the GET parameter with [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) because is_null() will assert the var equals to `NULL`.